# Loading CSV data on server, converting data to JSON and getting result using Json Queries using Golang

Tags: json, csv, go, tcp, tcpserver

I am trying to build a TCP server that loads dataset from a **CSV** file and provide an interface to query the dataset. TCP server will expose port 4040. CSV file contains the following columns related to corona virus cases:

- Cumulative Test Positive
- Cumulative Tests Performed
- Date
- Discharged
- Expired
- Admitted
- Region
  Users should be able to connect to the server using **NetCat** `nc localhost 4040` command on Linux/Unix based systems.

Once connected to TCP, the user should be able to communicate with the application by sending queries in JSON format.

```
{
    "query": {
        "region": "Sindh"
    }
}
```

```
{
    "query": {
        "date": "2020-03-20"
    }
}
```

My server.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

type CovidPatient struct {
    Positive    string      `json:"Covid_Positive"`
    Performed   string      `json:"Coivd_Performed"`
    Date        string      `json:"Covid_Date"`
    Discharged  string      `json:"Covid_Discharged"`
    Expired     string      `json:"Covid_Expired"`
    Region      string      `json:"Covid_Region"`
    Admitted    string      `json:"Covid_Admitted"`
}

type DataRequest struct {   
    Get string `json:"get"`
}

type DataError struct {     
    Error string `json:"Covid_error"`
}

func Load(path string) []CovidPatient {
    table := make([]CovidPatient, 0)
    var patient CovidPatient
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    csvData, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    for _, row := range csvData{
        patient.Positive =  row[0]
        patient.Performed =  row[1]
        patient.Date =       row[2]
        patient.Discharged = row[3]
        patient.Expired =    row[4]
        patient.Region =     row[5]
        patient.Admitted =   row[6]
        table = append(table, patient)
    }
    return table
}

func Find(table []CovidPatient, filter string) []CovidPatient {
    if filter == "" || filter == "*" {
        return table
    }
    result := make([]CovidPatient, 0)
    filter = strings.ToUpper(filter)
    for _, cp := range table {
        if cp.Date == filter ||
            cp.Region == filter ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Positive), filter)      ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Performed), filter)     ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Date), filter)          ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Discharged), filter)    ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Expired), filter)       ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Region), filter)        ||
            strings.Contains(strings.ToUpper(cp.Admitted), filter){
            result = append(result, cp)
        }
    }
    return result
}

var (
    patientsDetail = Load("./covid_final_data.csv")
)

func main(){
    var addr string
    var network string
    flag.StringVar(&addr, "e", ":4040", "service endpoint [ip addr or socket path]")
    flag.StringVar(&network, "n", "tcp", "network protocol [tcp,unix]")
    flag.Parse()

    switch network {
    case "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6", "unix":
    default:
        fmt.Println("unsupported network protocol")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    ln, err := net.Listen(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    log.Println("Covid19 Condition in Pakistan")
    log.Printf("Service started: (%s) %s\n", network, addr)
    
    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            conn.Close()
            continue
        }
        log.Println("Connected to ", conn.RemoteAddr())
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer func() {
        if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Println("error closing connection:", err)
        }
    }()

    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(conn, 4)

    for {
        buf, err := reader.ReadSlice('}')
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Println("connection read error:", err)
                return
            }
        }
        reader.Reset(conn)
        
        var req DataRequest
        if err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &req); err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to unmarshal request:", err)
            cerr, jerr := json.Marshal(DataError{Error: err.Error()})
            if jerr != nil {
                log.Println("failed to marshal DataError:", jerr)
                continue
            }
            if _, werr := conn.Write(cerr); werr != nil {
                log.Println("failed to write to DataError:", werr)
                return
            }
            continue
        }

        result := Find(patientsDetail, req.Get)

        rsp, err := json.Marshal(&result)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to marshal data:", err)
            if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(conn, `{"data_error":"internal error"}`); err != nil {
                log.Printf("failed to write to client: %v", err)
                return
            }
            continue
        }
        if _, err := conn.Write(rsp); err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to write response:", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly loads the csv and convert it into JSON. But, when I try to run query using NetCat command it return empty JSON element. Kindly guide me where is error.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you want this:

```
╭─root@DESKTOP-OCDRD7Q ~
╰─# nc localhost 4040
{"get": "Sindh"}
[{"Covid_Positive":"1","Coivd_Performed":"1","Covid_Date":"1","Covid_Discharged":"1","Covid_Expired":"1","Covid_Region":"Sindh","Covid_Admitted":"1"}]
```

What you should do is just to modify your json request.

---

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

type CovidPatient struct {
    Positive   string `json:"Covid_Positive"`
    Performed  string `json:"Coivd_Performed"`
    Date       string `json:"Covid_Date"`
    Discharged string `json:"Covid_Discharged"`
    Expired    string `json:"Covid_Expired"`
    Region     string `json:"Covid_Region"`
    Admitted   string `json:"Covid_Admitted"`
}

type DataRequest struct {
    Get CovidPatient `json:"get"`
}

type DataError struct {
    Error string `json:"Covid_error"`
}

func Load(path string) []CovidPatient {
    table := make([]CovidPatient, 0)
    var patient CovidPatient
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    csvData, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    for _, row := range csvData {
        patient.Positive = row[0]
        patient.Performed = row[1]
        patient.Date = row[2]
        patient.Discharged = row[3]
        patient.Expired = row[4]
        patient.Region = row[5]
        patient.Admitted = row[6]
        table = append(table, patient)
    }
    return table
}

func Find(table []CovidPatient, filter CovidPatient) []CovidPatient {

    result := make([]CovidPatient, 0)

    log.Println(filter, table)

    for _, cp := range table {

        if filter.Positive == "" {
        } else if filter.Positive != cp.Positive {
            continue
        }
        if filter.Performed == "" {
        } else if filter.Performed != cp.Performed {
            continue
        }
        if filter.Date == "" {
        } else if filter.Date != cp.Date {
            continue
        }
        if filter.Discharged == "" {
        } else if filter.Discharged != cp.Discharged {
            continue
        }
        if filter.Expired == "" {
        } else if filter.Expired != cp.Expired {
            continue
        }
        if filter.Region == "" {
        } else if filter.Region != cp.Region {
            continue
        }
        if filter.Admitted == "" {
        } else if filter.Admitted != cp.Admitted {
            continue
        }

        result = append(result, cp)
    }
    return result

}

var (
    patientsDetail = Load("./covid_final_data.csv")
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile | log.Ltime)
    var addr string
    var network string
    flag.StringVar(&addr, "e", ":4040", "service endpoint [ip addr or socket path]")
    flag.StringVar(&network, "n", "tcp", "network protocol [tcp,unix]")
    flag.Parse()

    switch network {
    case "tcp", "tcp4", "tcp6", "unix":
    default:
        fmt.Println("unsupported network protocol")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    ln, err := net.Listen(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    log.Println("Covid19 Condition in Pakistan")
    log.Printf("Service started: (%s) %s\n", network, addr)

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            conn.Close()
            continue
        }
        log.Println("Connected to ", conn.RemoteAddr())
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer func() {
        if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Println("error closing connection:", err)
        }
    }()

    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(conn, 100)

    for {
        buf, err := reader.ReadBytes('|')
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Println("connection read error:", err)
                return
            }
        }
        reader.Reset(conn)

        var req DataRequest
        if err := json.Unmarshal(buf[:len(buf)-1], &req); err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to unmarshal request:", string(buf), err)
            cerr, jerr := json.Marshal(DataError{Error: err.Error()})
            if jerr != nil {
                log.Println("failed to marshal DataError:", jerr)
                continue
            }
            if _, werr := conn.Write(cerr); werr != nil {
                log.Println("failed to write to DataError:", werr)
                return
            }
            continue
        }

        result := Find(patientsDetail, req.Get)

        rsp, err := json.Marshal(&result)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to marshal data:", err)
            if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(conn, `{"data_error":"internal error"}`); err != nil {
                log.Printf("failed to write to client: %v", err)
                return
            }
            continue
        }
        if _, err := conn.Write(rsp); err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to write response:", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

The query is:

```
╭─root@DESKTOP-OCDRD7Q ~
╰─# nc localhost 4040                                                                                             127 ↵
{
    "get": {
        "Covid_Region": "Sindh",
        "Covid_Date": "2020-03-20"
    }
}|
[{"Covid_Positive":"1","Coivd_Performed":"1","Covid_Date":"2020-03-20","Covid_Discharged":"1","Covid_Expired":"1","Covid_Region":"Sindh","Covid_Admitted":"1"}]
```

Comment: I have tried it but I want outcome to be according to region and date. That is why my query is written like that. Can you please further explain.

Comment: @ZubadIbrahim Both region and date? Give me some time, it needs coding.

Comment: @ZubadIbrahim I updated the answer for you. 1. Include your struct in your query. 2. Set a delimiter for your query (my is '|'). 3. Modify your filter func (just a simple one, need to be improved).

Comment: I tried this solution, the server is connecting but not returning anything.

Comment: The terminal is showing the following error:
server1.go:164: failed to unmarshal request: {
    "get": {
        "Covid_Region": "Sindh",
        "Covid_Date": "2020-03-20"
    }
}

Comment: @ZubadIbrahim Did u completely copy my code? Or did u add the "|" when you query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220658/discussion-between-p1gd0g-and-zubad-ibrahim).

Comment: I didn't used "|". Now I am trying it. Wait for a moment.

Comment: @ZubadIbrahim "|" is not necessary, any delimiter is ok. Maybe you could push your code somewhere, I'll have a look for u. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Inside function `handleConnection`, the first thing is "read until you find the first `}`", imagine the user is sending the request:

```
{ "get": { "Covid_Region": "Sindh", "Covid_Date": "2020-03-20" } }
```

then that step read:

```
{ "get": { "Covid_Region": "Sindh", "Covid_Date": "2020-03-20" }
```

Notice the trailing `}` is missing, then the `json.Unmarshal` is trying to unmarshal the query without the last `}` (which is an invalid json).

This problem can take advantage of JSON streaming decoding, in other words, use `json.NewDecoder(r io.Reader)` instead of `json.Unmarshal`. Let me copy and modify the first part of that function:

```
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer func() {
        if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Println("error closing connection:", err)
        }
    }()

    jsonDecoder := json.NewDecoder(conn) // A json decoder read a stream to find a
                                         // valid JSON and stop just the byte
                                         // after the JSON ends. Process can be
                                         // repeated.

    for {
        var req DataRequest
        err := jsonDecoder.Decode(&req)
        if err == io.EOF {
            log.Println("finish")
            return
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("unmarshal:", err)
            return
        }

        result := Find(patientsDetail, req.Get) // Here query the system

        // ...
```

Probably now it works, but you can also take advantage of json streaming to send the response back with a `jsonEncoder := json.NewEncoder(conn)` before de for loop and sending the request like this:

```
        err := jsonEncoder.Encode(&result)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("failed to marshal data:", err)
            // ...
            continue
        }
```